# Rerender Apex Chart after getting async Data

Tags: angular, asynchronous, apexcharts, rerender

I want to visualize some data from an API with an APEX-chart in angular. As the datafetching takes a while, the chart is rendered as an empty chart before the data is loaded. Is there a way to rerender the chart or to wait for the data before rendering the chart?

```
//service component

import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class DataService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  datax: any;
  xTime: any[] = [];
  yValue: any[] = [];


  getDayData(): Observable<any> {
    let url = "http://localhost:4997/activepowerL1?DateTime=1620352800000";
    return this.http.get(url);
  }
}
```

````
// component.ts

  constructor(private data: DataService) {
    this.data.getDayData().subscribe((data) => {
      this.data.datax = data;
      console.log(this.data.datax[1].DateTime);

      this.data.xTime = [];
      this.data.yValue = [];

      for (let dataelt of this.data.datax) {
        this.data.xTime.push(String(new Date(new Date(dataelt.DateTime)).toISOString().slice(11, 16)));
        this.data.yValue.push(parseFloat(dataelt.Value));
      }

      console.log(this.data.xTime);
    });
}

```
```
//component.html

          <div id="chart">
            <apx-chart
              [series]="chartOptions.series"
              [chart]="chartOptions.chart"
              [xaxis]="chartOptions.xaxis"
              [dataLabels]="chartOptions.dataLabels"
            ></apx-chart>
          </div>
```
````

Comment: You can can put an *ngIf=“data” on the apx-chart component?

Comment: That doesnt work for me. Even if i use a function isData() to set data=true by clicking a button there is no rerendering.

Comment: Right. There are some weird things in your code. Like this: this.data.datax = data;

Comment: Oh yeah thanks you're right thats redundant. But that doesn't affect the outcome

Answer (score 0):

I've recently faced with similar re-rendering issue, found 2 possible solutions:

1. **Use [updateSeries](https://apexcharts.com/docs/methods/) from apexchart APi**: allows to update the series array overriding the existing one

   Ex:

   ```
   var chart = new ApexCharts(el, options);
   chart.updateSeries([{
     data: [{
       x: "02-02-2002",
       y: 44
     }, {
       x: "12-02-2002",
       y: 51
     }]
   }])
   ```
2. **Trigger Change Detection**: after updating the data source, you can manually trigger change detection to ensure that the chart component re-renders with the new data

   Ex:

   ```
   this.dataService.getChartData().subscribe((data) => {
     this.chartData = data;
     this.cdr.detectChanges(); // Trigger change detection
   });
   ```